# Missing resource files when building apk with apktool

Tags: android, android-xml, apktool

Once I've decompiled an apk using apk tool, I have tried to build it. The error I am getting is several lines looking similar to this:

```
forest\res\layout\activity_main.xml:19: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/menu_btn').
forest\res\layout\activity_main.xml:67: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/forest_sidebar_entrance').
```

I am using the most recent version (apktool_2.3.4) and have made sure I am using the correct frameworks. It seems that the program can't find some pictures declared in the xmls. I have also tried to look for these pictures manually such as "menu_btn", "down_arrow","prev_btn" and did not find them in the decoded files either. Did apktool decode the apk incorrectly or are the files simply missing? If so, would it be okay to simply delete these lines from the xml files? The apk should be running fine since I extracted the apk directly from my phone. I also tried using a downloaded apk from the playstore using a firefox extension.

edit: added activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/mainview_drawerLayout" android:clipChildren="false" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/mainview_shareroot" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/mainview_root" android:background="@color/colorLightGreen" android:clipChildren="false" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="667">
            <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="35" />
            <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="35">
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/mainview_coinview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="375">
                    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="365">
                        <cc.forestapp.activities.main.plant.PlantCoinInfoView android:layout_gravity="end" android:id="@+id/mainview_coininfoview" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
                    </FrameLayout>
                    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="10" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <cc.forestapp.activities.main.plant.PlantModeToggleView android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/mainview_modetoggleview" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="375">
                    <View android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="10" />
                    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="45">
                        <ImageView android:id="@+id/mainview_menubutton" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/menu_btn" android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
                        <ImageView android:id="@+id/mainview_backbutton" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/back_btn2" android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="375">
                    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="10" />
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/mainview_edittag" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/edit_note_btn" android:layout_weight="45" />
                    <LinearLayout android:gravity="end" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="265">
                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" android:id="@+id/mainview_songname" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/RainForest" android:maxLines="1" android:alpha="0" />
                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" android:id="@+id/mainview_choosesonghint" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/bgsound_note_label_text" android:maxLines="1" android:alpha="0" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/mainview_musicbutton" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/headphone_mute_btn" android:layout_weight="45" />
                    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="10" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
            <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="5" />
            <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/mainview_participantroot" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:weightSum="375" android:layout_weight="45">
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/mainview_participantsview" android:scrollbars="none" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="297" android:overScrollMode="never" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/mainview_toptextroot" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="70">
                <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/mainview_phraseroot" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="375">
                    <TextView android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/mainview_phrasetext" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="@string/home_screen_message_bad" android:layout_weight="315" android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.35" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/mainview_roomroot" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <TextView android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/mainview_roomtokentext" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.35" />
                    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="65" android:layout_marginStart="5dp" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mainview_roomtokentext">
                        <ImageView android:id="@+id/mainview_roomsharebutton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="0dp" android:src="@drawable/android_share_btn_black" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:tint="@color/colorWhite" android:layout_weight="35" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/mainview_resulttoproot" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <TextView android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" android:ellipsize="end" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/mainview_resulttext" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:maxLines="3" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1" />
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/mainview_whybutton" android:layout_width="25dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/failure_reason_btn" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_marginStart="5dp" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mainview_resulttext" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
            <cc.forestapp.activities.main.plant.AdjustPlantView android:id="@+id/mainview_adjustview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="242" />
            <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="235">
                <include android:id="@+id/mainview_plantbotview" layout="@layout/layout_main_plant" />
                <include android:id="@+id/mainview_growingbotview" layout="@layout/layout_main_growing" />
                <include android:id="@+id/mainview_resultbotview" layout="@layout/layout_main_result" />
            </FrameLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/mainview_adview" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <com.jetradarmobile.snowfall.SnowfallView android:id="@+id/mainview_snowfallview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" app:snowflakeAlphaMax="255" app:snowflakeAlphaMin="128" app:snowflakeImage="@drawable/snowball" app:snowflakeSizeMax="30dp" app:snowflakeSizeMin="10dp" app:snowflakeSpeedMax="5" app:snowflakeSpeedMin="1" app:snowflakesFadingEnabled="true" app:snowflakesNum="40" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="start" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/mainview_sidemenuroot" android:background="@color/colorLightGreen" android:layout_width="190dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="667">
        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="70" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/mainview_sidemenu" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="547" />
        <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/mainview_sidemenu_h5root" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:weightSum="190">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/mainview_sidemenu_h5entrance" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/forest_sidebar_entrance" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:layout_weight="140" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="50">
            <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/mainview_sidemenu_footericon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="20dp" android:src="@drawable/web_logo" android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I: Using Apktool 2.3.2

```
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building resources...
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\activity_main.xml:19: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/menu_btn').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\activity_main.xml:67: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/forest_sidebar_entrance').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\activity_main.xml:70: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/web_logo').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\activity_profile.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/report_user_btn').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\activity_realtree.xml:91: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/real_tree_page_back_btn').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\activity_statistics.xml:16: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/down_arrow').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\activity_statistics.xml:39: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/prev_btn').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\activity_statistics.xml:44: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/next_btn').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\activity_timeline.xml:12: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/phone_usage_btn').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\activity_usage.xml:38: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/prev_btn').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\activity_usage.xml:42: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/next_btn').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\activity_usage.xml:86: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/arrow').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\com_facebook_tooltip_bubble.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/com_facebook_tooltip_blue_background').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\com_facebook_tooltip_bubble.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/com_facebook_tooltip_blue_xout').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\com_facebook_tooltip_bubble.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/com_facebook_tooltip_blue_topnub').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\com_facebook_tooltip_bubble.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/com_facebook_tooltip_blue_bottomnub').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\dialog_crashreport.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/diagnosis').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\dialog_h5.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/h5dialog_button').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\dialog_h5.xml:36: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/popup_close_btn').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\dialog_note.xml:15: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/solid_tag').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\dialog_realtree.xml:13: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/sapling').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\dialog_showcoin.xml:19: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ad_video_icon').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\dialog_sleeptown.xml:31: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/popup_close_btn').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\dialog_sunshine_error.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/sunshine_error').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\dialog_togethertutorial.xml:19: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/popup_close_btn').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\intercom_composer_view_layout.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/intercom_composer_ic_send').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout-v21\intercom_composer_view_layout.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/intercom_composer_ic_send').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\intercom_default_launcher.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/intercom_circular_shadow').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\intercom_default_launcher.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/intercom_launcher_icon').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\intercom_expander_button.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/intercom_composer_gallery_expand').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout-v21\intercom_expander_button.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/intercom_composer_gallery_expand').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\intercom_preview_chat_full_overlay.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/intercom_circular_shadow').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\intercom_preview_chat_snippet_overlay.xml:11: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/intercom_circular_shadow').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\layout_foregound_notification.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\layout_foregound_notification.xml:21: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/plant_ball').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\listitem_avatar.xml:12: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'placeholderImage' with value '@drawable/together_dead_flag').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\listitem_managefriend_login.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_blue').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\listitem_managefriend_login.xml:17: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/down_arrow').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\listitem_shrinkwrapper.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'actualImageResource' with value '@drawable/expand').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\listitem_soloplant.xml:17: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/more_option_btn').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\listitem_tag.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/checkmark').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\listitem_tagcolor.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/checkmark').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\listitem_togetherplant.xml:17: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/more_option_btn').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\listitem_unlockspecies.xml:17: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'placeholderImage' with value '@drawable/unlocked_tree_card_soil').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\share_forest.xml:27: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/tag_btn').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\ucrop_controls.xml:12: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ucrop_ic_scale').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\ucrop_controls.xml:15: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ucrop_ic_crop').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\ucrop_controls.xml:18: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ucrop_ic_rotate').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\ucrop_layout_rotate_wheel.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ucrop_ic_reset').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\layout\ucrop_layout_rotate_wheel.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ucrop_ic_angle').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_btn_check_material.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_btn_check_material.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_btn_radio_material.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_015').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_btn_radio_material.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_edit_text_material.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_edit_text_material.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_edit_text_material.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable-v21\abc_edit_text_material.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable-v21\abc_edit_text_material.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable-v21\abc_edit_text_material.xml:12: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_item_background_holo_dark.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_item_background_holo_dark.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_item_background_holo_dark.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_focused_holo').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_item_background_holo_light.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_item_background_holo_light.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_item_background_holo_light.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_focused_holo').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_longpressed_holo').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_pressed_holo_light').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_longpressed_holo').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_holo_dark.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_holo_dark.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_holo_dark.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_focused_holo').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_holo_light.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_holo_light.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_holo_light.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_focused_holo').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_indicator_material.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_star_black_36dp').
W:
W: C:\Users\aguay\Desktop\reverse\forest\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_indicator_material.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_star_half_black_36dp').
```

Comment: Please add your activity_main.xml

Comment: Try again with APKTool 2.3.2.

Comment: @MatanKintzlinger added!

Comment: @TheWanderer Also did not work using 2.3.2, I've added the error log above

Comment: Do you have these drwable files in you drawable folder in you project?

Comment: @MatanKintzlinger No these files are not appearing in the drawables folder. That's why I was wondering if maybe the apktool decompiled incorrectly or if these files were always missing in the apk

Comment: @MisaelAguayo what is the command you used in order to decompile the APK file?

Comment: @MatanKintzlinger I used "apktool d forest.apk" to decompile and "apktool b forest" to build

Comment: Try to use `apktool d -r forest.apk` to decompile (the `-r` tells the apktool to not decompile the resources

Comment: @MatanKintzlinger I tried that and it built but when installing to my device, it would crash. I think it has to do with the actual apk I have. Other apps are working fine. Thank you for your help!